# Solidity Code Feedback - Basic Task Tracking Storage and Retrieval

Tags: solidity

I just completed some basic Solidity tutorials and wanted to try my hand at a basic task tracker...it basically allows users to create tasks and assign them to a user and a project.

My biggest question is around the mapping portions.  If I want to easily retrieve all the tasks for a given project or all the tasks for a given user, is my implementation correct?  Are there any ways my use of:

```
uint256 newIndex = _taskList.length;
 _taskList.push(Task(project, title, description, false, dueDate, assignedUser, msg.value, msg.sender));
_userTasks[assignedUser].push(newIndex);
_projectTasks[project].push(newIndex);
```

Could result in bad information due to race conditions or simultaneous calls?  Any and all comments are appreciated, thank you!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract ProjectTaskList {
    
    struct Task {
        string project;
        string title;
        string description;
        bool isCompleted;
        uint256 dueDate;
        address assignedUser;
        uint256 payment;
        address owner;
    }

    Task[] public _taskList;
    mapping(address => uint256[])  _userTasks;
    mapping(string => uint256[] )  _projectTasks;

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function addToDo(string memory project, string memory title, string memory description, uint256 dueDate, address assignedUser) public payable {
        require(bytes(project).length > 0, "Project is required");
        require(bytes(title).length > 0, "Title is required");
        require(bytes(description).length > 0, "Description is required");
        require(dueDate > 0, "DueDate is required");
        require(assignedUser != address(0), "Assigned User is required");

        uint256 newIndex = _taskList.length;
        _taskList.push(Task(project, title, description, false, dueDate, assignedUser, msg.value, msg.sender));
        _userTasks[assignedUser].push(newIndex);
        _projectTasks[project].push(newIndex);
    }

    function getUserTasks(address user) public view returns (uint256[] memory){
        return _userTasks[user];
    }

    function geProjectTasks(string memory projectName) public view returns (uint256[] memory){
        return _projectTasks[projectName];
    }

    function updateTask(uint256 index, string memory project, string memory title, string memory description, uint256 dueDate, address assignedUser){
        require(bytes(project).length > 0, "Project is required");
        require(bytes(title).length > 0, "Title is required");
        require(bytes(description).length > 0, "Description is required");
        require(dueDate > 0, "DueDate is required");
        require(assignedUser != address(0), "Assigned User is required");

        Task foundTask = _taskList[index];
        require(foundTask.owner == msg.sender, "You do not have the right to update this task");
        // more code to see if the user or project has been assigned and update the Project and User array correctly
        // then update the code
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides lack of commenting, I don't see a major issue with your code. Maybe some gas optimizations would be doable

1. You could limit the sizes of `project` and `title` fields. EVM stores data in chunks of 256 bits. So using 128 bits for each of them(preferably less) would cost less gas since EVM will take care of both in a single chunk
2. You already keep assigned user in your struct. Using a second `mapping` for user task might seem faster and cleaner, but storage operations are costly. A getter function for that purpose would be cheaper.
3. Same as (2), but with project tasks mapping.
4. You can't have race conditions. EVM has no concept of parallelism.

Comment: Thank you so mu for the feedback, for commenting, I've added NatSpec style commenting earlier today
1.  Good idea on the field lengths
2.  What would be the correct way to write a getter function?  My background is JS and C# where I have array.filter, array.map or LINQ queries to quickly find items in lists/arrays.  Is there a solidity equivalent or am I stuck doing for loops to iterate through lists looking for values?

Comment: yeap, good old fashioned iteration